# Англичане вышли в лидеры нашей группы

Tags: стилистика

Это правильный газетный заголовок или в нем есть стилистическая ошибка?

Answer (score 1):

Не вижу ошибки. Никакой. Даже не знаю, в чем тут можно усомниться.

**Выйти в лидеры** - нормально, как в прямом значении (на скачках, например), так и в переносном, "лидер" вообще слово с широким спектром применения.

**Лидер группы** - а почему нет-то?!

Если вопрос о том, можно ли заметить "сборная Англии" на **англичане**, так это вообще повсеместно.

**"Наша группа"**? Не обсуждается. Наша - та, где мы, наша сборная.

Или я чего-то недопонимаю?

(+)------ 19.06.2016

Я почитал комментарии, появилось робкое предположение.
На основании вашего сравнения "лидера" с "передовиком" делаю вывод, что неправильно понимаете само слово лидер и выражение "выйти в лидеры". Лидер - это идущий впереди в прямом смысле, а не - как "передовик" - в переносном. Это не качество, это состояние. Идет колонна солдат - впереди лидер колонны (ну только он там по-другому называется). Прошла команда "Кругом! Шагом марш!" - лидер стал другим.

Это не качество, это ***состояние***. К "передовику" в его нынешнем состоянии имеет весьма косвенное состояние. Да, в переносном значение передовика можно назвать лидером. Но только в переносном. Само "передовик" развилось из переносного значения слова первый, "лидер" же этим пока не страдает. Ну если только в политическом контексте, но и там "лидер партии" - незыблемо. И там в лидеры не выходят, а выдвигаются, выбираются и т. д.

Comment: Мне кажется, что правильно: стали лидерами нашей группы или вышли в лидеры в нашей группе. А то получается, что предлог В управляет сочетанием "лидеры нашей группы", хотя правильное выражение - это просто "вышли в лидеры". Как-то на слух мне этот  заголовок не понравился.

Comment: Ой... В голову бы не пришло, что именно вам не понравилась. На мой взлгяд - наоборот, предлог, если речь идет о "Лидер группы" ну совсем не нужен. какой-то совершенно другой смысл получается. Именно в ***лидеры нашей группы*** англичане и вышли, *"лидеры - чего?"*, а не "лидеры - где?".

Comment: Посмотрела примеры   в Нацкорпусе: (1)Собственно, именно на этом они и вышли в лидеры мировой экономики. Карлос Рейтеманн, выиграв несколько гонок, вышел в лидеры чемпионата мира, (2) Автомобили этого предприятия вышли в лидеры именно в малых классах. Может быть, ТАК ПРИНЯТО ГОВОРИТЬ,  но мне кажется, что "вышел в лидеры" - это устойчивое выражение, а мы распространяем его несогласованным определением. Равноценными мне кажутся такие выражения: стать лидерами группы  и стать лидерами в группе. (Но, возможно, я просто мало слушаю спортивных передач).

Comment: А "вышли в лидеры ГРУППЫ" (перешли в какое качество?) у вас тоже вызывает сомнения или проблема только в сочетании с "нашей"? Сама по себе конкретизация качества не должна вызывать сомнения в том, можно ли говорить о переходе в такое качество: ср. "попасть в БОЛЬШИЕ забияки". Добавленная притяжательность тоже конкретизирует названное качество: не просто "лидеры группы", а лидеры вполне определённой группы (той, где играем и мы). Для меня это безобиднее громоздкого двухпредложного "выйти в лидеры в нашей группе".

Comment: ВЫЙТИ 4. Достичь какого-л. положения, состояния; стать кем-л., каким-л. В. в начальники. В. в передовики, в отличники.  Мне кажется, что форма В.п., совпадающая с И.п. (выражение неодушевленности), делает это выражение устойчивым и ограничивает  возможности  его свободного распространения. Можно, к примеру, сказать: "Он вышел в передовики нашего завода"?

Comment: В последнем выражении мне мешает только добавленное "нашего" - видимо, добавление субъективного момента к качеству не вполне уместно, в то время как дополнение "завода" я воспринимаю полезным - как часть общего понятия "передовик завода (= передовик труда в рамках своего завода)": простое "в передовики" излишне абстрактно и мало о чём говорит (ясно только, что это позитивная перемена).

Comment: @Alex_ander, ко мне вопросы есть?

Comment: @Sibylla *но мне кажется, что "вышел в лидеры" - это устойчивое выражение* - на чем это основано? Оно, может, и устойчивое, но ни о каком фразеологизме, запрещающем перестановку, замену или  дополнение составляющих не может быть и речи. Здесь в прямом смысле лидер, в прямом смысле "вышел", а "лидер группы" - вполне естественное сочетание. Каких еще блох тут можно искать, не понимаю. В отношении "передовика завода" - то в принципе ничего плохого я том не вижу, но ситуация в чем-то противоположная. "Передовик" - это что-то типа звания, оно вполне может использоваться безотносительно к чету-то.

Comment: @Sibylla А вот "лидер" само по себе, без уточнения "чего" - это корабль, в таком значении безнадежно устарело. Еще может использоваться по отношению к лошади, идущей первой: лидер ="лидер забега". Или к искусственному зайцу на собачьих бегах и т. п. В остальных случаях - лидер только "чего". Да вы и сами это видите по своим примерам из нацкорпуса. Так объясните мне, почему кто-то или что-то не может ***выйти*** именно  ***в лидеры группы***?! "Лидер чего угодно" - нормально. "Выйти куда угодно" - тоже. "Выйти в туалет" можно, а "в туалет на втором этаже" - нет?! Это я еще пример подобрал...

Comment: Мне эта фраза сначала просто не понравилась на слух, и я спросила у человека, который не связан с филологией,  но обычно верно угадывает правильную форму. Он сказал не раздумывая, что выражение неверно, но почему - не знает. Ну а я стала думать, что с ним не так, и мне вот  что кажется. Здесь используется форма И.п., которая обозначает В.п., то есть выражена категория неодушевленности, а лидеры, передовики, начальники - одушевленные существительные. Поэтому выражение кажется устойчивым, не расположенным к увеличению своего объема. В противном случае эта неодушевленность напрягает слух.

Comment: >> *Поэтому выражение кажется устойчивым, не расположенным к увеличению своего объема.* То бишь выйти в начальники можно, а выйти в начальники отдела - напрягает?! ))

Comment: @Niemand, может вы таки пойдете в чат?

Comment: @Niemand вот и хренейте себе в чате. А писать комментарии под мои постом, если я Вам не нужен, извольте адресно.